# Problems with Software Sources -- I tried to add a Repository and it failed. How do I fix it?

Tags: ppa, repository

As in the title. I tried to add a Repository, how do I remove it. It won't let me via the software-sources program. I tried `sudo ppa-purge ppa:quantal` (the name of it) and it failed anyone got any ideas?

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal main restricted universe multiverse

deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal main restricted universe multiverse #Added by software-properties

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-security main restricted universe multiverse

deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-security main restricted universe multiverse #Added by software-properties

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates main restricted universe multiverse #Added by software-properties

deb http://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/amd64/ quantal

deb-src http://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/amd64/ quantal
```

Comment: give us the details, which ppa, what have you executed. I highly doubt there will be any ppa named `quantal` because it's name of ubuntu 12.10. What is the content of sources file?

Comment: well I would if I could open software sources to check

Comment: Post content of the following file. open `sources.lst` file in gedit, located at `/etc/apt/`

Comment: I've added it to the description not enough space in the comments.

Comment: Does the directory /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ contain any files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just open up *terminal* (ctrl+alt+T) and post the commands: [Replacing *gedit* with your favourite *text editor*]

```
gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and *remove* all references to the *faulty repository.*